# Is the application on hyperledger-fabric centralized?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I started learning hyperledger-fabric for creating my own business application but, I still have a question :

In practice, there is only one machine with docker and whole bna, or every member must have his own docker with bna?

If only one, then it turns out to be a centralized application. Am I right?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice, you would expect every Org on the network to have at least one peer. Each org would have its own CA server (or cryptogen), and use shared Orderers. It is 1 business network (Definition is embedded in the genesis block). If, as you ask, there was only one Org, it would be centralized.

Comment: For example, I need an application with many factories for the production of buttons, I should have one peer, in which there are my factories as business network applications, right? Or I have incorrect understanding of peer?

Comment: I don't understand the question. A business network is a collection of Organizations. Organizations have their own peers. Peers maintain copies of the shared ledger and (probably) participate in consensus. Organizations and business networks are logical constructs. Peers are physical servers.

Comment: Ok, you told about orderers, the orderer stores the blockhain, right? what information is stored in the blockchain? I'm sorry that I'm jumping from the question to the question, but I want to understand, and holes in knowledge are obtained a lot